# LoadError when requiring a renamed gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I started building Ruby [bindings](https://github.com/O-I/marvel) for the Marvel Comics API earlier this month. At the time, there was no gem named `marvel` on RubyGems, so I fired up jeweler, created a project, and began making a crude, but useable first release. I tested it by `rake install`ing it locally and requiring it in a dummy project that let me play with it in `pry`:

```
require 'marvel'
require 'dotenv'
require 'pry'

Dotenv.load

@client = Marvel::Client.new

@client.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['API_KEY']
  config.private_key = ENV['PRIVATE_KEY']
end

binding.pry
```

When I got to the point where I had exposed several endpoints (at this [commit](https://github.com/O-I/marvel/commit/6cc7b2865b15bb60927505e5bda6f48830721d4e)) I attempted releasing it to rubygems.org, but discovered someone by then had released a `marvel` gem. I hastily altered my Rakefile and renamed mine to `marvel_api` and released it.

I let it sit for a few days before I came back and started experimenting with adding in Faraday middleware to try and clean it up. However, I never seem to have tested whether the name change to `marvel_api` worked. Now, whenever I try to `require marvel_api`, I'm met with this LoadError:

```
/Users/Raevynheart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- marvel_api (LoadError)
from /Users/Raevynheart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm trying to understand if this is happening because my process for renaming the gem was incorrect, or if this is some separate issue. The gem's source is here: https://github.com/O-I/marvel. Note that the repo name and gem name are different — I don't know if that is an issue. Let me know if there is any other information I need to add to help troubleshoot this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are facing this issue since within your gem's `lib` directory, you still have the file named as `marvel.rb`.

From http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/ :

> Code for your package is placed within the lib directory. The convention is to have one Ruby file with the same name as your gem, since that gets loaded when require 'hola' is run. That one file is in charge of setting up your gem’s code and API.

So, I believe your issue will resolve by changing your filename within lib to marvel_api.rb.

Comment: You are correct, @Sam. Thank you very much for getting me unstuck. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)